# Having <link rel="icon"> and the favicon.ico in the root, but the favicon still not display

Tags: html, wordpress, icons, favicon

My site is already have this in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://i2.wp.com/xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-2.png?fit=32%2C32&#038;ssl=1" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://i2.wp.com/xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-2.png?fit=192%2C192&#038;ssl=1" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://i2.wp.com/xn--qucu-hr5aza.cc/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-2.png?fit=180%2C180&#038;ssl=1" />
```

It also have a favicon.ico in the root folder (the one having index.php). Yet the favicon still doesn't show up. What is more weird is that it does show up when I'm in the admin panel. Do you know why?

<sub>Here is the [page](https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com?utm_source=SE%20%C2%BB%20Stack%20Overflow%20%C2%BB%20favicon%20not%20display&utm_medium=Homepage&utm_campaign=Homepage) if you need to examine.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be loading for me fine? Perhaps it's your browser cache?

You could try uploading the favicon via the WordPress Customize. From the WP admin, Appearance > Customize > Site Identity. From there you can upload the icon. That will display the favicon in both the frontend and backend.

I have found this way to be more reliable as WordPress will automatically create `/favicon.ico`, however be aware this won't be a physical file. You'll also have to move your current `favicon.ico` file out of the WP root for this to work should you use it.

Comment: It works for you? It doesn't work for me even on phone. Yes I uploaded the icon that way